# Getting "Permission Denied" error when trying to build a docker image in Jenkins on Mac

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am using Jenkins version 2.121.1 with Pipeline On MacOS-HighSierra.

I've a shell script called build_docker_image.sh that builds a docker image using the following command:

```
docker build -t test_api:1 -f test-dockerfile
```

test-dockerfile is a Dockerfile and has instructions to build an image.

From CLI the whole set up works! However, when I run it from Jenkins server Pipeline context, it is failing at the above line with an error:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=.dockerfile.14bce80e6f0b4b9d7b36&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=2fab4ca31a7ca7b7eceddf80e02de5a7089dc10f50db250d2249e059d7ecfb61&shmsize=0&t=login_api%3A100_i&target=&ulimits=null:
>   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

The step that triggers from Jenkins server is simple. Just call the script:

```
stage ('Build-Docker-Image') {
    steps {
        sh '/path/to/build-docker_image.sh'
    }
 }
```

I made sure Jenkins user has "admin" permission and member of "staff" group. I printed out them in the shell script too as below:

> WHOAMI   jenkins ID =  uid=267(jenkins) gid=267(jenkins)
>   egid=1(daemon)
>   groups=267(jenkins),12(everyone),20(staff),61(localaccounts),80(admin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)

I followed the workaround steps mentioned here: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/799. I've rebooted Docker on my Mac several times too. It did not help.

Comment: What does the rest of the `Jenkinsfile` look like, especially the agent it is running on

Comment: Jenkinsfile does not have much, as I want to keep it simple during development.

`pipeline {
    agent  any
    tools { 
        maven '3.5.2' 
        jdk 'JDK8' 
    }
  
    environment {
        PATH="${PATH}:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin"
    }
    stages {      
      stage ('Build-Docker-Image') {
     steps {
          sh '/path/to/build-docker_image.sh'
     }
 }  
    } //end of stages   
}`

Comment: ok, and do you have agents attached or is jenkins running in docker itself?

Comment: I am running Jenkins as a server on my Mac. I am not running it inside a docker container. Hope I got your question correctly.

Comment: OK are you running https://www.docker.com/docker-mac and is the docker service running?

Comment: Yes. I use Docker For Mac, Community Edition Version 18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312) and it is running.

Comment: one more piece of information. 

`sudo -s -u jenkins

Password:

bash-3.2$ whoami

jenkins

bash-3.2$ id

uid=267(jenkins) gid=267(jenkins) groups=267(jenkins),12(everyone),20(staff),61(localaccounts),80(admin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer), snip...

bash-3.2$ docker ps -a
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174470/discussion-between-user2995358-and-keepcalmandcarryon).

Answer (score 0):

I see:

```
id uid=267(jenkins) gid=267(jenkins) groups=267(jenkins),12(everyone),20(staff),61(localaccounts),80(admin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer)
```

I don't see the group docker in that list:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

Restart Jenkins and see if the issue persists.

On a different note, I always use [`mesosphere/dcos-jenkins-dind-agent/Dockerfile.alpine`](https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-jenkins-dind-agent/blob/master/Dockerfile.alpine) as a Jenkins agent, for my build involving docker, precisely because I do not want to share the main host `/var/run/docker.sock`

If my build does a `docker system prune --force`, that can have devastating effects on my host images/containers/volumes, even though the command was intended only for local builds docker artifacts.

On Mac, the thread "[No more ‘docker’ group](https://forums.docker.com/t/no-more-docker-group/9123)" suggests:

```
docker run ... --group-add staff
```

Check [this example](https://github.com/ehazlett/.dotfiles/blob/adb2d118dabe16fe073e060f1ca688a9e37467d4/bashrc#L262-L283):

```
macdev() {
    CMD=${2:-/bin/bash}
    set_title "dev : $1"
    local name=dev-$1
    docker inspect $name > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        docker attach $name
    else
        docker run -ti --restart=always \
            -e PROJECT=$1 \
            --net=host \
            --name=$name \
            -v $HOME/.vim:/home/ehazlett/.vim \
            -v $HOME/.vimrc:/home/ehazlett/.vimrc \
            -v $HOME/.bashrc:/home/ehazlett/.bashrc \
            -v $HOME/.ssh/config:/home/ehazlett/.ssh/config \
            -v ~/Sync:/home/ehazlett/Sync \
            -v ~/.docker:/home/ehazlett/.docker \
            -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
            --group-add staff \
            ehazlett/devbox $CMD
    fi
}
```

Comment: I am on Mac. "usermod" does not work. There is no "docker" group on my system. 

My regular user for which docker works has same set of permissions.
id
`uid=501(myuser) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),501(access_bpf),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)`

Comment: More info. Used dscl command to change the GID of jenkins. 

Now my regular user for which docker works and jenkins have same permissions. Just the UIDs are different. 
permissions are:
`gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),501(access_bpf),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),snip...`

Reboot both docker and jenkins server. Still the same issue.

Comment: @user2995358 would https://forums.docker.com/t/no-more-docker-group/9123 help then?

Comment: @user2995358 as in https://github.com/ehazlett/.dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc#L262-L283: `docker run... --group-add staff`

Comment: I saw that. --group-add is not a valid option for docker build command

Comment: Started a topic on Docker On Mac forum too. https://forums.docker.com/t/getting-permission-denied-error-when-trying-to-build-a-docker-image-in-jenkins-on-mac/53591

Thanks!